# Integer Linear Programs: An instance or not?

Tags: decision-problem, integer-programming

Given a set of integers $\{x_0, x_1, ... , x_{n-1}, x_n\} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, a set of integer variables $\{y_0, y_1, ... ,y_{n-1}, y_n\} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ and an integer $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ is the following equation an instance of an integer linear program (ILP):

$
(x_1\cdot y_1) + (x_1\cdot y_1) + \cdots + (x_{n-1}\cdot y_{n-1}) + (x_n\cdot y_n) = m
$
i.e. is there an assignment of variables $y_i$ such that the equation is true?
After googling around I noticed that ILPs usually involve maximising or minimising a variable, but that is not what is needed here. If not, could anyone tell me what type of problem this is and if there are any known complexity results?

Comment: Add optimisation criterion $\max 1$ and you are good to go; the search for an admissable solution remains.

Comment: This is a [Diophantine equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation).

Comment: thanks @FalkHüffner, i found a similar question here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29254/complexity-of-linear-diophantine-equations seems like they are solvable in P-Time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has a solution if and only if $m$ is a multiple of the greatest common divisor of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. You can compute the GCD in polynomial time using the Euclidean algorithm (the version where you divide in each step rather than subtract) applied $n-1$ times.

Comment: Is this true even if  $m,x_i$ and $y_i$ can be BOTH positive and negative integers?

Comment: Yes, and in fact you have to allow the $y_i$ to be positive, negative, or zero. Otherwise this criterion is not correct.

Comment: My apologies, but i actually got my criteria wrong. I have updated the answer - the variables are now limited to N instead of Z. I assume that the GCD mechanism no longer works?

Comment: This is related to the *coin problem* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem). It's better if you rolled back your change and asked a new question, so that this answer remains relevant.